# Error: Incorrect number of arguments (5), expecting 4 for 'rlang_quos_interp'

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I am getting the following error while trying to create a graph in `ggplot`:

```
    Error in dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
    Incorrect number of arguments (5), expecting 4 for 'rlang_quos_interp'
```

My code was working a couple of days ago and I'm not sure what has happened. A similar error occurs when I try to plot graphs or export tables in `jtools`

I tried updating and loading `rlang` and this is what happens. Are these two issues related?

```
    Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
    namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘tibble’, ‘pillar’ so cannot be 
    unloaded
    Error in library(rlang) : 
    Package ‘rlang’ version 0.2.2.9001 cannot be unloaded
```

`tibble` and `pillar` load fine

Here is the graph I tried to create in `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(Pie2, aes(x=ReefType, y=Pielou, fill=ReefType)) + 
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",
       colour="black", # Use black outlines,
       size=.3, width = 0.6) +     
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Pielou-se, ymax=Pielou+se),
            size=.3,   
            width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9)) +
xlab("ReefType") +
ylab("Rockfish/100"~m^2) +
scale_fill_manual(values=cbBlueGreen, name="ReefType", # Legend label, 
                breaks=c("AR", "NR"),
                labels=c("Artificial Reef", "Natural Reef")) +
ggtitle("Rockfish Density in Natural vs. Artificial Reefs") +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:100) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = 
element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = 
"black"))
```

> 

and the functions that aren't working in `jtools` are `export_summs` and `plot_summs`

Answer (score 4):

After quite some time of struggling to understand this error, I upgraded to the latest version of R/RStudio. Everything works again! It turns out that my version had begun causing trouble with some of the necessary packages.

After the update, this code was very helpful in re-installing each package and all of the dependencies (supporting packages) required:

```
install.packages("PACKAGE", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

** type the name of the package you are installing under "PACKAGE"

My apologies to those who downvoted me for asking an inappropriate question, I am new to R and still have trouble correctly interpreting errors. Any feedback on how to improve next time would be appreciated.